# asynchronously running org-toggle-latex-fragment

Tags: org-mode, latex, preview-latex, async

In orgmode, it is quite useful to view the equations inline. However, sometimes this can take a while to execute. Running `org-toggle-latex-fragment` asynchronously would be quite useful. However, most of what I can find about async is about how to execute external commands in an async way. I did try this post (https://emacspeak.blogspot.com/2018/07/using-emacs-threads-to-execute-commands.html?m=1) and emacs-aio (https://github.com/skeeto/emacs-aio)  but it did not quite work/ I could not get it to work.

Please let me know if anyone here knows how to execute this function in an async way.

Thank you for your response!

Comment: This question is too broad. Ask one question at the time. About alternatives (that translate the LaTeX fragments asynchronously): Try [texfrag](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/texfrag) available [on melpa](https://melpa.org/#/texfrag).

Comment: Just use `start-process` or `make-process` and do all the work in sentinels or in hooks of such. That is enough for LaTeX fragments.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks! I narrowed the scope of what I was looking for. I will check out texfrag.

Comment: @Tobias Can you clarify a bit? If you mean start an asynchronous process - How does one do that? I tried emacs-aio but could not get it to work.

Comment: I think, now I am slowly getting what you are actually asking. Could you please check my edit? Do you want to run the specific function `org-toggle-latex-fragment` asynchronously? What I meant with using `start-process` is to run LaTeX that way. That is the hard way of doing all the processing oneself.

Comment: `texfrag` completely replaces the LaTeX strategy of orgmode with that one of `preview-latex`. After installing `texfrag` run `M-x texfrag-mode` in the orgmode buffer. You get a TeX menu with most of the menu entries of the `Preview` menu of AucTeX. The strategy of `preview-latex` is different from that one of orgmode. `preview-latex` does many steps in a asynchronous way. You can work with Emacs while the overlays for the LaTeX fragments are generated.

Comment: Orgmode on the other hand checks per sha1 keys whether fragments are modified and only processes that ones. The image files for the processed fragments have that key in their name. Maybe, the check takes too long in big documents.

Comment: texfrag actually does what I want but has another issue. The images are generated by dvipng (instead of dvisvgm that I used to use) and on a mac the resolution is lacking and the images are blurry. I know that Yamamoto's emacs-mac (https://auctex.gnu.narkive.com/VIELjyjv/embedded-previews-in-high-dpi) is supposed to resolve this issue, but it did not work when I tried it. Do you think it is possible to improve the resolution for preview-latex on mac without using his patch?

Comment: I don't have a Mac for testing. So we need to cooperate for solving the Retina resolution problem. Please join [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100735/asynchronously-running-org-toggle-latex-fragment). It may take a while for a response 1-day delays are quite common.